# Creating an array of structs with macro in Systemverilog

Tags: arrays, struct, module, macros, system-verilog

I've created a module with (example) two in and two out-puts. The definition of every in and output is delcared through a macro.

Is it possible to create it a bit more elegant (later usability)? Something like an array of inputs and outputs (NAME(i), in(i), out(i))?

It would be helpful, because i am later using much more out and inputs and there is a possbility using later loops to access the in/outputs much more elegant.

top:

```
`include "macro.sv"

module top (in_0, in_1, out_0, out_1);

    `STRUCT_i(in_0_temp,  10);
    `STRUCT_i(in_1_temp,  22);
    `STRUCT_i(out_0_temp,  55);
    `STRUCT_i(out_1_temp,  99);

    input   `STRUCT(in_0_temp)      in_0;
    input   `STRUCT(in_1_temp)      in_1;
    output  `STRUCT(out_0_temp)     out_0;
    output  `STRUCT(out_1_temp)     out_1;

...

    endmodule
```

Macro.sv :

```
`define STRUCT(NAME) \
struct_i_``NAME``

`define STRUCT_i(NAME, DATA) \
typedef struct packed { \
  logic [DATA:0]            info; \
  logic                     test1; \
  logic                     test2; \
    } `STRUCT(NAME)
```

Comment: Macros definitions do not belong inside packages. They are global to the current compilation unit. See http://go.mentor.com/package-import-versus-include

Comment: Did you try arrays of structures in input/outputs which are supported by SV as per section 5.10 of LRM?

Comment: An array of structs won't work here because it seems each element needs to be a different type.

Comment: Yes each element needs to be a different type, that is my problem. There is no option to do this with an array?
Oh i've mixed something with copy paste (package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with an array because, by definition, an array is a collection of uniformly typed variables. Access with a dynamic index value requires that each element have an identical layout. It would not work even with simple bit vectors of different lengths. Your only synthesizable option is to declare `info` with a max size and hope the unused bits are optimized away.